# How to access global variable from inside class's function

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have file `init.php`:

```
<?php 
     require_once 'config.php';
     init::load();
?>
```

with `config.php`:

```
<?php 
     $config = array('db'=>'abc','host'=>'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx',);
?>
```

A class with name `something.php`:

```
<?php
     class something{
           public function __contruct(){}
           public function doIt(){
                  global $config;
                  var_dump($config); // NULL  
           }
     } 
?>
```

Why is it null?
In php.net, they told me that I can access but in reality is not .
I tried but have no idea.
I am using php 5.5.9.

Comment: did you include`config.php`? just include and print $config

Comment: Hands off from globals!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$config` in `config.php` is not global.

To make it a global variable, which i do NOT suggest you have to write the magic word `global` in front of it.

I would suggest you to read [superglobal variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp).

And a little bit of [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

What I would suggest is to make a class which handles you this.

That should look something like

```
class Config
{
    static $config = array ('something' => 1);

    static function get($name, $default = null)
    {
        if (isset (self::$config[$name])) {
            return self::$config[$name];
        } else {
            return $default;
        }
    }
}

Config::get('something'); // returns 1;
```

Comment: omg! then `$config` won't be consider as global variable??? i thought that  i require_once/ include then PHP will see it as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use Singleton Pattern like this

```
<?php
     class Configs {
        protected static $_instance; 
        private $configs =[];
        private function __construct() {        
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if (self::$_instance === null) {
                self::$_instance = new self;   
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        private function __clone() {
        }

        private function __wakeup() {
        }     
        public function setConfigs($configs){
         $this->configs = $configs;
        }
        public function getConfigs(){
         return $this->configs;
        }
    }

Configs::getInstance()->setConfigs(['db'=>'abc','host'=>'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx']);

     class Something{
           public function __contruct(){}
           public function doIt(){
                  return Configs::getInstance()->getConfigs();
           }
     } 
var_dump((new Something)->doIt());
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the file like this:

```
 include("config.php"); 
     class something{ ..
```

and print the array as `var_dump($config);` no need of global.

Answer (score 1):

Change your class a bit to pass a variable on the constructor.

```
<?php
     class something{
           private $config;
           public function __contruct($config){
               $this->config = $config;
           }
           public function doIt(){
                  var_dump($this->config); // NULL  
           }
     } 
?>
```

Then, if you

1. include `config.php`
2. include `yourClassFile.php`

and do,

```
<?php
$my_class = new something($config);
$my_class->doIt();
?>
```

It should work.

Note: It is always good not to use `Globals` (in a place where we could avoid them)